# how to get the list of product under an id in vue js

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to get the list product  under an id or title

this is my json object

```
{
    "status": true,
    "product": {
        "_id": "625672a8370e769a8a93a51e",
        "title": "iphone",
        "description": "Lorem ",
    }
}
```

this is my script tag to get the list of product under the title

```
<script>

import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      product: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${this.$route.params.id}`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.product = response.data.product;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error;
      });
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.product = response.data.product;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error;
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

this is my route

```
 {path: "/products/:title", name: "Product", component: Product},
```

this is how i go to the route to get the specific product

```
 <router-link :to="`/products/${product.title}`">
          <img
            :src="product.photo"
            alt="Placeholder image"
          >
        </router-link>
```

this is what i get in my url

```
http://localhost:8080/products/iphone
```

but the list of product doesn't display,  but when i change my route to

```
 {path: "/products/:id", name: "Product", component: Product},
```

i get the list of products, please how can i go about this

this is the error i get

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/products/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: First of all, why do you call two `Axios` methods and both set `product`? –

Comment: i dont think thats the problem if i change {{product.title}} to {{product._id}} i get a reponse when i go to the id

Comment: There are a lot of problems in your code, any can cause the issue, also some details are missing, Please try to provide full example of code, you can use stackoverflow snippet or any live editor like codesandbox.